# How do I include a menu on every page on my Wordpress site?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site that uses an index.php that contains a menu structure that appears only on the index. I'd like to add that menu selection to each page. The menu is executed with javascript.

```
                        <div class="filternav" id="maintabs">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a id="newsid" href="javascript:showonlyone('news');" title="View Latest Activity" class="active">Latest</a></li>
                                <li><a class="" id="outlineid" href="javascript:showonlyone('outline');" title="View Course Outline">Outline</a></li>
                                <li><a id="assignmentsid" href="javascript:showonlyone('assignments');" title="View Only Assignments" class="">Assignments</a></li>
                                <li><a class="" id="linkstextsid" href="javascript:showonlyone('linkstexts');" title="View Links & Media Resources">Resources</a></li>
                                <li><a id="peopleid" title="View by People" href="javascript:showonlyone('people');" class="mpix">f</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Clicking "Outline" on the index.php page lists all posts categorized with that id.

Is there anyway to create href links on subpages to execute the javascript when the links are clicked on subpages.

The function is

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
                 $('div[name|="pane"]').each(function(index) {
                      if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
                            $(".filternav a").removeClass("active");
                            $("#"+thechosenone+"id").addClass("active");

                           $(this).fadeIn(150);
                      }
                      else {
                           $(this).fadeOut(150);
                      }
                 });
            }
```

I've tried adding these elements to the page.php

Answer (score 0):

Is it your custom theme or are you editing some existing one? Check the [WP template hierarchy docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#visual-overview). There is a list of PHP files with their backup template files.

If your theme contained only the `index.php`, it would be sufficient to put your code only in there. Usually though you'd need to include it also in `single.php`, `page.php`, `archive.php`, `search.php` and `home.php` (and probably more).

One of the possible approaches would be creating `menu.php` file and then including it in all files needed using [include()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). Another option would be putting the menu to `header.php` or `footer.php` as these are already included in all files metioned.